# OS media cataloguer with custom catagories

Tags: windows, open-source, media-manager

Must be open source. The manager should be last updated sooner than 2 years ago and be able to create custom categories. It would be very nice if the media manager could also download data off internet and be able to sync with various cataloguing websites. A build in recommendation engine would be great.

- Must be Open Source
- Must be Windows, others a plus
- recently updated
- custom categories
- download media data
- upload to social cataloguing sites
- recommendation engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a [lot of searching](https://alternativeto.net/list/2554/recommender-systems-apps-for-the-end-user-) I only found [coolector](http://www.thecoolector.com) and [tribler](http://www.tribler.org) .
And those are a stretch. Coolector is not OS and its recsys is weak. Tribler is for completely anon stuff and its recsys is very niche.